# How to show windows 7 like message for rename a file with invalid characters

Tags: c#, listview, file-rename

In my windows form application, I have a list-view which is used to import and use images in project.
I am doing validations on rename of an image using 'AfterlabelEdit' Event of list view.
In case, if invalid characters are entered, instead of showing error message how can i use windows7 / 8 like message.
[image: Win 7 Error]
Which control I need to use ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this visual effect using a [tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984424(v=vs.71).aspx), with the [`IsBalloon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.isballoon(v=vs.110).aspx) property set to `true`, although positioning it correctly on your listview is going to be fiddly, likely requiring some cunning [Win32 API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_USER) calls.